# How to autostart TightVNC on Fedora 14 upon booting

Tags: linux, fedora, fedora-14, tightvnc

Is that possible to do it by just using the `rc.local`?

Or in the OS startup section, by entering `gnome terminal --profile 'xxx' -e 'xxxxxx'` ?

I tried both methods above but neither of them works.
Anyone knows how to add it to Fedora 14's startup?

The terminal command to start TightVNC is:
`su`, followed by `service vncservice start`

Answer (score 0):

Simply uncomment/add the appropriate lines in your: **/etc/xinetd.d/vnc** and **/etc/services**, there's a tutorial [here](http://codeghar.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/remote-login-with-gdm-and-vnc-on-fedora-11/).